# "Operation must use an updateable query" in Access with MYSQL backend and a really simple query

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I have read a lot of possible solutions for this error, even some on here, but it seems my issue does not fall into the same genre as theirs do. Mine is way too simple which really confuses me.

I am running Access 2013 as the front end, MYSQL 8.0.23 on the back end, and MYSQL ODBC connector 8.0.23 Win32.

When I run (either through VBA or directly from a Query):

```
UPDATE Account1 SET LC = (Select Land_Company from Parameters2)
```

I get the error. If I just run `Select Land_Company from Parameters2` it returns 420. If I then run:

```
UPDATE Account1 SET LC = 420
```

it works fine.

Both the Account1 and Parameters2 table have PKs. There is one and only one record in the Account1 table. I have also tried:

```
UPDATE Account1 SET LC = (Select Land_Company from Parameters2) where ID=4
```

so that it could only affect one row as ID is the primary key. I even tried:

```
UPDATE DISTINCTROW Account1 SET LC = (Select Land_Company from Parameters2) where ID=4
```

which does not work either. Both Account1.LC and Parameters.Land_Company are INT so there isn't a conversion issue. Am I overlooking something simple?

So, to help out I shortened the actual query I am running to that above, the query in my code that failed originally was:

```
Update Account1 Set Other_Expenses=(Select Sum(Expenses.Amount) from Expenses INNER JOIN Accounts On Accounts.Account_Number=Expenses.Account Where Accounts.Account_Type=10 and Expenses.Account <> '60000345' and Expenses.Account <> '60000115' and Expenses.Account <> '60000270' and Expenses.Account <> '17000230' and Expenses.Account <> '60000015' and Expenses.Account <> '40000005' and Expenses.Account <> '40000035' and Expenses.Account <> '60000190' and Expenses.Land_Company =420 and Expenses.Date>= '2020-01-01' and Expenses.Date<= '2020-12-31')
```

I am guessing that if I fix why the simple query doesn't work I can fix the longer query. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: The "really simple query" is actually 2 queries (side note, the `WHERE` clause could use a `NOT IN (...)`, and they're both going to have to run anyway - have you considered running them separately and parameterizing the outer one with the output of the inner query?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [DLookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) expression instead of a subquery to retrieve that `Land_Company` value from the `Parameters2` table:

```sql
UPDATE Account1 
SET LC = DLookup('Land_Company', 'Parameters2')
WHERE ID = 4;
```

Comment: I very much appreciate the idea, but I need to find out why it doesn't work, not find a workaround. The reason is because this is the simplest query that fails with this error, the actual query is much longer...

Comment: Update Account1 Set Other_Expenses=(Select Sum(Expenses.Amount) from Expenses INNER JOIN Accounts On Accounts.Account_Number=Expenses.Account Where Accounts.Account_Type=10 and Expenses.Account <> '60000345' and Expenses.Account <> '60000115' and Expenses.Account <> '60000270' and Expenses.Account <> '17000230' and Expenses.Account <> '60000015' and Expenses.Account <> '40000005' and Expenses.Account <> '40000035' and Expenses.Account <> '60000190' and Expenses.Land_Company =420 and Expenses.Date>= '2020-01-01' and Expenses.Date<= '2020-12-31')

Comment: My suspicion was the subquery caused Access to treat the `UPDATE` as not updateable.  So I used `DLookup` to fetch the same value which was returned by the subquery.  Did it work?

Comment: So how do I stop access from treating it as not updatable using pure SQL code?

Comment: @AllanHall you run the inner query first, and use its output to parameterize the outer query, if the driver won't let you kill two birds with the same stone.

Comment: Also.. `WHERE ... AND Expenses.Account NOT IN ('600000345','600000115','600000270','17000230','600000015','40000005','40000035','600000190') AND ...` ;-)

Comment: Mathieu, thank you, I will look into the driver and maybe see if the MYSQL ODBC driver has a setting for this. Also, thanks for the cleanup on isle 5, they got added one at a time over a bunch of years and I never just fixed it :-)